# Did the Clave visit Jocelyn while she lived in New York?

Tags: mortal-instruments, shadowhunters, infernal-devices

In "City of Bones", Clary learns that her mom was a Shadowhunter and has broken away from the Clave. However, I recently read "Clockwork Angel", and in it, Jem explains to Tessa that when Shadowhunters leave the Clave, and have children, then the Clave visits them every 6 years to ask if they want to leave their parents and join them. Did this happen with Clary, and it was just wiped from her mind? Or was Jocelyn hiding from the Clave to the point where they actually didn't know where she was? And having read "Clockwork Angel", why would Magnus not report Jocelyn to the Clave, seeing as how he always wants to be on the Clave's good side?

Comment: I have not read that one, but in the first book it is implied that Jocelyn is in hiding, which would include hiding from The Clave.  Also, Magnus only acts that way because of Alex.  Before that, he would generally abide by the accords, but did not really care what The Clave thought of him or his actions.

Comment: @DaveJohnson: Magnus acts this way in "Clockwork Angel" as well. I'm beginning to believe it's fully in his nature.

Answer (score 0):

In City of Glass, Luke and Clary are walking from Lake Lyn after Clary portaled them there. They walk through the Necropolis, and see Jocelyn's tombstone. 
The Clave did not know that Jocelyn was still alive, so they wouldn't try and visit her.

However, if they had known about her existence, they would have visited her, and Clary's memory would have been wiped by Magnus, as Jocelyn would have wanted her mind wiped.